# Golang io.Copy blocks in internal ReadFrom

Tags: go

I am building a terminal emulator in golang and I was trying to run detached processes from which I can copy output and display it to the user but the io.Copy function blocks and hence I cannot continue to the output part

I looked in the source code and it blocks in the internal ReadFrom method, I cannot understand why this is happening

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    inputReader, inputWriter, _ := os.Pipe()
    outputReader, outputWriter, _ := os.Pipe()

    io.Copy(inputWriter, bytes.NewReader([]byte("\n")))

    stdin := inputReader
    stdout := outputWriter
    stderr := outputWriter

    var attr = os.ProcAttr{
        Dir: "/tmp",
        Env: nil,
        Files: []*os.File{
            stdin,
            stdout,
            stderr,
        },
        Sys: nil,
    }

    process, startProcessErr := os.StartProcess("/usr/bin/ls", []string{"ls"}, &attr)
    if startProcessErr != nil {
        panic(startProcessErr)
    }

    if releaseProcessErr := process.Release(); releaseProcessErr != nil {
        panic(releaseProcessErr)
    }

    var output bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&output, outputReader)
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Maybe it is because I release the process but I dont think it should happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `io.Copy(&output, outputReader)` blocks until read on `outputReader` returns EOF or some other error.  Read on `outputReader` does not return EOF because the write side of the pipe is still open in the parent process.  Fix by closing the writer in the parent process.

```
...

if releaseProcessErr := process.Release(); releaseProcessErr != nil {
    panic(releaseProcessErr)
}

outputWriter.Close() // <-- add this line

var output bytes.Buffer
io.Copy(&output, outputReader)
fmt.Println(output)

...
```

Use the [os/exec](https://godoc.org/os/exec) package to simplify the code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/ls")
cmd.Dir = "/tmp"
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(output))
```

Comment: I'd use `outputWriter.Close` to make things clearer (to me anyway), but I'd also ditch the local variables named `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` so then I'd *have* to do that. :-)

Comment: but why does io.Copy not flush the writer buffer?

Comment: @SolskGaer I don't understand the your question.   Which buffer are you referring to?